# 0 item price in cart when add to cart after place order

Tags: magento2.2, rest-api

I'm building Mobile Magento 2 application with REST API. I'm using the following endpoint to add an item to cart

```
/V1/carts/mine/items
```

Then I'm placing an order with

```
/V1/carts/mine/order
```

After place order when I add a product to cart first time it has 0 price for an item in the cart.

I've tried to debug on the Magento side and I see that collectTotals for quote produce 0 price, but I'm not sure why. Any ideas here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging I've found out that shippingAddress entity is missed inside the quote and totals calculation isn't correct. So my workaround here is simple invoke

```
$quote->getShippingAddress();
```

before adding an item to cart.

Here is my plugin code

```
// app/code/My/Module/etc/di.xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\Repository">
        <plugin sortOrder="1" name="myModuleRepository" type="My\Module\Plugin\Model\Quote\Item\RepositoryPlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>


// app/code/My/Module/Plugin/Model/Quote/Item.php
<?php

namespace My\Module\Plugin\Model\Quote\Item;

class RepositoryPlugin
{
    /**
     * Quote repository.
     *
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $quoteRepository;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
    ) {
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    }

    public function beforeSave(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\Repository $subject,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface $cartItem
    )
    {
        $cartId = $cartItem->getQuoteId();
        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
        $quote->getShippingAddress();
    }
}
```